# Prevent duplicate action when multiple storage keys are modified

Tags: javascript, local-storage, dom-events, addeventlistener

I've been learning JavaScript for about a month now, and right now I’m working on a little project (Shopping Cart) to dive into storage events. I’ve successfully managed to store a few keys from “tab1” into the local storage and retrieve them from “tab2”. However, I came across a particular “problem”, which I’ve been struggling with for the last couple of days.

On “tab1” I have five keys that are being stored in localStorage. on “tab2” I need to complete an action (create an HTML element) every time the localStorage changes. The problem is that the action is being triggered once for every key that’s changed. In other words, I keep getting 5 duplicate HTML elements.

I’ve spent many hours searching for answers on forums, YouTube videos, blogs and of course here. So far no luck. I’ve also been reading the documentation on localStorage, but since I’m new at this, it’s not very clear for me.

I hope you can help find a solution or understand why I keep getting these duplicate actions.

This is an example of the code I have so far:

```
let itemList = document.getElementById("itemList");
let summaryItem = document.getElementById("summaryItem_01");
let summaryImage = document.getElementById("itemImage_01");
let summaryName = document.getElementById("item_Name_01");
let summaryModel = document.getElementById("itemModel_01");
let summaryQuantity = document.getElementById("detailQuantityDisplay_01");
let summaryPrice = document.getElementById("itemPriceAmount_01");

//Gets localStorage info on page load and feeds summaryItem fields.
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let itemImage = localStorage.getItem("modalItemImage");
    let itemName = localStorage.getItem("modalItemName");
    let itemModel = localStorage.getItem("modalItemModel");
    let itemQuantity = localStorage.getItem("modalItemQuantity");
    let itemPrice = localStorage.getItem("modalItemUnitPrice");

    //Prints localStorage info to summaryItem element.
    summaryImage.setAttribute("src", itemImage);
    summaryName.innerText = itemName;
    summaryModel.innerText = itemModel;
    summaryQuantity.value = itemQuantity;
    summaryPrice.innerText = itemPrice;
});

//This is where I'm getting the duplicate action
window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
    let a = document.createElement("article");
    itemList.appendChild(a);
});
```

UPDATE:
After MauriceNino's suggestion, I ended up with this code and it worked perfectly:

```
//Tab1

let modalItem = {
    modalItemImage: displayModalImage.innerHTML.slice(10, -2),
    modalItemName: displayModalName.innerText,
    modalItemModel: displayModalModel.innerText,
    modalItemQuantity: displayModalQty.value,
    modalItemUnitPrice: displayModalPrice.innerText,
    modalItemTotal: displayModalTotal.innerText,
  };

  localStorage.setItem("modalItem", JSON.stringify(modalItem));

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

//Tab2

//Gets localStorage info from modal
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("modalItem"));
  let dataArray = Object.values(data);

  let itemImage = dataArray[0];
  let itemName = dataArray[1];
  let itemModel = dataArray[2];
  let itemQuantity = dataArray[3];
  let itemPrice = dataArray[4];

//Prints localStorage info to summaryItem element.
  summaryImage.setAttribute("src", itemImage);
  summaryName.innerText = itemName;
  summaryModel.innerText = itemModel;
  summaryQuantity.value = itemQuantity;
  summaryPrice.innerText = itemPrice;

//Creates new summaryItem when there's a chnage on localStorage.
window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
  let a = document.createElement("article");
  itemList.appendChild(a);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just save it as one element like so:

```
//Gets localStorage info on page load and feeds summaryItem fields.
window.addEventListener("load", () => { 
    // Get all the data in a single statement
    let { itemImage, itemName, itemModel, itemQuantity, itemPrice } 
          = localStorage.getItem("modalItem");

    //Prints localStorage info to summaryItem element.
    summaryImage.setAttribute("src", itemImage);
    // ...
});

//Will be called only once now
window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
    let a = document.createElement("article");
    itemList.appendChild(a);
});

// This is where you are saving your localStorage settings
localStorage.setItem("modalItem", { 
    itemImage: 'image', 
    itemName: 'name', 
    itemModel: 'model', 
    itemQuantity: 2, 
    itemPrice: 3
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer was right on the spot. I knew the solution had to be something simple but I just couldn't see it. I guess I'm living the newbie life.

However, I'd like to point out that I had to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse in order to write/read the object. But it worked perfectly. Once again, thank you for helping me see what I was missing!